# How do I deal with a with a PC who is a bully?

Tags: problem-players

So I have been playing with this person in a campaign for almost two years at this point and I am beginning to see a pattern with how his characters interact with mine. Here are the points that I have seen:

1. His characters will take any opportunity to jab, belittle and/or undermine my characters. Even when I do not interact with his characters in certain scenarios, he will always find a way to say something snide to my character specifically.  I could say that the sky is blue and he would still find a way to say something. There have been times where my character is unconscious for in game days on end and he will still mock my character. It is also important to note that nobody laughs at the things he says.
2. If I ever say anything snide or jab back in any form, not only will his character get angry, he  as a player will get angry as well. If I challenge him about how much crap he flings at my character, he will pull up a laundry list of things I have done to his character that he perceives as slights. In more than one case he has threatened my character with violence twice, all because my character decided to call him out on why he wanted to kill a prisoner who was showing no signs of resistance. The worst part is that he is okay with attacking other PCs. He has done it with a previous character to another. Even though it did make sense with that character (He was a lawman and watched another character steal in front of him who then tried to run right after a city was sieged), the character he is currently playing is a mercenary, and me being a warlock with a low AC, he could very easily jump my character and kill him.
3. He has both in character and out of character stated how much he hates the PC I am playing. It nearly comes up every single session. I am afraid of calling him out on this because once again, he will get angry and pull up a laundry list of any slights against his character. Any time my character tries to make peace with him, he will accept it in the moment but will get back to his normal antics within two sessions. He constantly makes jokes about how he is going to bang my PCs mom (Who he has seen) over and over, it's clearly not banter and it is him tormenting my character. Even when my character has brought out how uncomfortable it makes him, he ignores what my character has said and continues anyway. I know that if my character brought up anything touchy to his character, he would threaten my character's life or just outright try to kill him.

The reason I am posting this is because in this campaign, he has gone through three characters and is on number four, and each and every one has acted the same way toward my character.

I have talked to my DM about this and he is doing his best to stay neutral about the subject, but it is clear he has frustrations about this player. The other players do not get this amount of jabing thrown their way which makes this more confusing for me. I have talked to the player outside of sessions and about how he acts, but justifies it as "It's just in his character" before making it about how my PC has wronged him. Every time I try to address the issue that he puts forward he will move the goalpost every time, at a certain point we just go in circles with me becoming frustrated and him becoming angry.

I also wanted to say that we are playing online using Roll20.

I am sorry that this is a long post, I don't know how to make it shorter. I don't want to shout at him about my frustrations with how his characters make DND hard to enjoy at times. If anyone has any insight into this kind of situation, it would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Also [Player Characters all picking on one other PC](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/163929/52137)

Comment: @NepeneNep Please don't answer in comments.

Comment: I didn't, I asked a clarifying question which might lead to an edit which led to an open question.

Comment: @NepeneNep Asking "Have you tried [answer to the question]?" is not a clarifying question, it's an answer to the question.

Comment: This is an iterative question, like "Have you tried turning it on and off again." It's impossible to answer the question without knowing the intermediate steps they've taken to resolve it (aka, have they talked to others), and depending on what they suggest there may be a relevant question which doesn't deserve closing.

Comment: @NepeneNep Then ask your clarifying questions, but don't lead the querent to answers. If you want to know if they've talked to others, ask if they've talked to others and how it went. But don't continue down the path of what that means or how to do it - those are the purview of answers.